# multiple filters in an APEX 3.2 report

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I want to have multiple filters in an APEX report but it seems it's not possible? I'm new to apex so it's quite possible too I just don't know how to do it.

I've searched around the net and looked at the various settings in the APEX page but I can't find what I'm looking for.

Like in this screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTJdo.png

I can only have 1 filter available. I want to filter on other fields too **including fields which are not in the report columns**.

Is this possible? If yes, can you please teach me? thanks

Comment: What version of apex do you have? Have you taken a look at the actions > filter menu?

Comment: following on from Tom's comment have you looked at Interactive reports? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc/doc.42/e35125/ir_using.htm#BABFIIFF

Comment: Apex currently supports two types of report: Classic and Interactive. To answer this question we'll need to know what you've got at the moment.

Comment: thanks for the comments. I edited the title to reflect the version we're using.

Answer (score 0):

Columns that aren't displayed in your report are not rendered on your page, therefore you can not filter on them. If you want do so anyway, you need to create a filter based on page items, which you can append to your report query in the where clause.

e.g. create a page item P1_FILTER1 and reference it in your query as: "...where my_column = nvl(:P1_FILTER1,my_column)".

To ensure data consistency you can best create your page item as a select list.